TextView - Arabic text is truncated
I have a text display filled with Arabic. The text contains long sentences. Every line that has the longest sentence, the text is truncated. How to solve it?
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/tx1"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="17dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>

I have tried
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:gravity="right"


How about a multi-line TextView?
